# Write a single list to column

Tags: python, list

Using Python 2.7, i have a simple list where each element is composed by two numbers [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)] that i print on a output txt file, but it seems like this:

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

I want to print the list on a single column like this:

```
(1,2)
(3,4)
(5,6)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? There's a file writing module that makes this pretty easy, unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean by column.

Comment: Are you looking to print information you've read *from* a file or are you looking to write information *to* a file?

Comment: Too basic and specific to be of use to others.

Answer (score 0):

Print element by element and not the entire list. Printing in a file is just changing the print function for writing in a file. Like this:

```
>>> f = open('workfile.txt', 'w')
>>> l = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> for x in l:
...     f.write(str(x) + '\n')
...
```

And then if you look in workfile.txt with:

```
cat workfile.txt
```

You'll see:

> (1, 2) 
>   (3, 4) 
>   (5, 6)

Comment: Uhm ok, but i want to print the list on a txt file °w°

Comment: @Removed : 
 
If it worked mark the answer as solution please, it will be useful when other users search the solution about the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop.

```
>>> mylist = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
>>> for i in mylist:
...     print i
...
(1, 2)
(3, 4)
(5, 6)
```